# How does Mono's WinForms determine the system font size?

Tags: winforms, mono, autoscalemode

I wrote a C# application for Linux that is compiled by mono (`gmcs`) and uses the WinForms 2.0 library render a user interface.  My application looks fine on my computer, but one of my customers is a using a computer (a Fedora/[OLPC](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/The_OLPC_Wiki)) with a large font size, and the auto scaling did not totally work for him (text got bigger while user control sizes stayed the same).

If I could increase *my* font size and reproduce the problem on *my* Ubuntu computer, I'm sure I could fix the problem (by setting the right AutoScaleMode and AutoScaleDimensions for all of my controls).  **But when I try to increase my system font size in the *System -> Preferences -> Appearance* dialog, my font size settings do not seem to have any effect on the Winforms-rendered UI.**

**So, how does Mono WinForms determine the system font size?**  How can I make it choose a bigger size on my computer?

I am using Ubuntu 9.10 and Mono winforms 2.4.2.3+dfsg-2.

In case it matters, my application was ported from Visual Studio so the fonts on the control are set in .Designer.cs files like so:

```
label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Hans Passant gave the correct answer to this question, but his answer is no longer here, so I will answer my own question.)

The font size used by Mono Winforms is determined by the Resolution (DPI) setting in Ubuntu, which can be accessed by going to System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Fonts -> Details.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best off disabling AutoScaling:

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Winforms

Answer (score 0):

More common answer is: according to my experimentation, Mono calculates actual font size based on `Xft.dpi` value. It can be obtained using `xrdb -query Xft.dpi` and it can be dynamically set at run-time using `echo Xft.dpi: VALUE | xrdb`.

Note that some apps update their UI immediately after changing the value, and others (including Mono) check it only on startup.

Ubuntu's `System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Fonts -> Details` setting mentioned in David Grayson's answer will most likely change the same value.